# How to impletement nativescript-loading-indicator in Vue Native App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I M trying to implement nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator but not working properly in my Vue Native App

```
import {LoadingIndicator,Mode,OptionsCommon} from '@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator';
const indicator = new LoadingIndicator();


 export default {
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        mounted() {
            indicator.show();
            this.homeFirstbanner();
            this.justArrivals();
            this.getCategory();
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add appropriate code and/or possibly Playground sample of the issue.

Comment: Check once again i have edit my question

Comment: You are not adding `LoadingIndicator` to your Page / View. Include indicator in your template and bind busy attribute.

Comment: how can Include indicator in template and bind busy attribute? I m New In nativeScript Vue

Comment: It has nothing to do with {N}, just standard vue template. Just refer [docs for example](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/activity-indicator/)

Comment: I din't get that

Comment: Actually its just one page that i need the loader so dont want in template so trying to implement in App.js to direclty access from Components

Comment: Same example still applies. You can have a layout above your frame and put indicator inside. Probably use state management and bing busy attribute, update state from any component. If you are good with modal indicator, you may use the plugin mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Thanks i'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
const LoadingIndicator = require('@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator').LoadingIndicator;
const Mode = require('@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator').Mode;

const loader = new LoadingIndicator();
import { Page } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/page';

// optional options
// android and ios have some platform specific options
const options = {
  message: 'Loading...',
  details: 'Additional detail note!',
  progress: 0.65,
  margin: 10,
  dimBackground: true,
  color: '#4B9ED6', // color of indicator and labels
  // background box around indicator
  // hideBezel will override this if true
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  userInteractionEnabled: false, // default true. Set false so that the touches will fall through it.
  hideBezel: true, // default false, can hide the surrounding bezel
  mode: Mode.AnnularDeterminate, // see options below
  android: {
    view: page.getViewById('stackView'), // Target view to show on top of (Defaults to entire window)
    cancelable: true,
    cancelListener: function(dialog) {
      console.log('Loading cancelled');
    }
  },
  ios: {
    view: page.getViewById('stackView') // Target view to show on top of (Defaults to entire window)
  }
};

loader.show(options); // options is optional

// Do whatever it is you want to do while the loader is showing, then

loader.hide();
```

The view should be a valid uiView within your interface. Just give a StackLayout an Id, and target it.
ex: `view: page.getViewById("stackLayout")`

Pulled from [the plugin's example on npm](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator)

UPDATED

Comment: Got Error Msg UIView is not Defined